# Any application to scan non-standard QR codes

Tags: qr-code

Following [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/42361/20449). Typical QR Codes have control squares in three of four corners of each code:

[image]

It there any application or method available for Android system to scan non-standard QR Codes? For example:

1. QR Code with only one, central control square (I can't provide detail about company using these, because I've seen them in dozens of places, but I've heard, that many airlines uses these):

[image]

2. UPS diamond-codes / MaxiCodes:

[image]

I've tested many different QR Code reading applications in Google Play, but none of them were able to scan any of these non-standard QR Codes and all of them were limited to standard QR Codes only.

Comment: First of all: The examples you have given are no QR codes. They look similar, but use different techniques to store information. The first one should be an Aztec-Code. I know that there was an App called `barcode Scanner` that was able to read various barcodes and 2D codes, but it seems to have lost functionality; for me it only reads QR and bar codes, nothing else (no data matrix/Aztec codes).

Comment: I think this could be an answer.

Comment: Yuck... Just after answering it: recommendations like *Is there an app for X* are off-topic here (see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for details). But it had perfectly fit on [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)... That happens to one being active on both ends – I thought I was there :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[NeoReader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.gavitec.android)** should match your specification:

> - Scans all standard 1D and 2D code types – QR, Data Matrix, ***Aztec***, EAN, UPC, Code 39, Code 128, PDF 417 and more!
> - Automatic detection of code type

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

As [GiantTree](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/86358/gianttree) identified one of your non-standard codes as "Aztec", this app sounds promising. It doesn't explicitly mention your other candidate, but that could be covered by "and more" (or we simply were not able to connect it with one of the other names).

I've personally never used this app, as I only need EAN (1D) and standard QR codes – so I can give no personal experience here. But again, rating (4.2) and votes (>30,000) speak for it. If you want to check some alternatives, be welcome to take a look at my list of [Barcode Readers](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_barcode_scanner#group_28).

Comment: Thank you for a great answer, even though, it is for an off-topic question. BTW: "the other candidate" was already identified by me. It is [MaxiCode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MaxiCode).

Comment: Update: No, NeoReader is not able to read MaxiCodes ("the other candidate"). It does not recognize them on screen / on paper and when such image is uploaded to NeoReader (an option to recognize an image from library), it crashes.

Comment: Sad to hear that! Just discovered those are used e.g. by UPS. I only found [several low rated reader apps](http://www.appbrain.com/search?q=maxicode) explicitely mentioning them. Best rated amongst those is [Barcode Helper](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.markeu.scanmaster). Not updated since 2013, though.